# Meal Cart Being Overriden

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I am working on a delivery app but, I'm having a bit of trouble with my cart. The issue is this: Every time the customer adds a new item to their cart, everything in the cart takes the name of the most recent item. It only overwrites the tableView Object and doesn't affect my backend so, I know I imported something wrong.

For Clarity, I have two Tables: Product and Product Size that I'm bringing in Via JSON:

Product File:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class Product {
    //This pulls the information per product. Edit information here and attach to each Restaurant cell.

    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var short_description: String?
    var image: String?
    var type: String?
    var size: String?

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.id = json["id"].int
        self.name = json["name"].string
        self.short_description = json["short_description"].string
        self.image = json["image"].string
        self.type = json["course"].string
    }
}
```

Product Size:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class ProductSize {
    //Label for product information

    var price:Float?
    var sizeId: Int?
    var size: Int?
    var product_id: Int?

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.price = json["price"].float
        self.sizeId = json["id"].int
        self.size = json["size"].int
        self.product_id = json["product_id"].int
    }
```

The Meal is passed to us from the previous view controller here:

```html
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "cartInfo" {
     
            let controller = segue.destination as! CartController
            controller.product = product
            
        }
    }
```

In the Cart Controller, I display all the meals in the cart but, it only shows up with the same meal over and over.

```
    var product: Product?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shoppingCartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell

            let cart = Cart.currentCart.items[indexPath.row]
            let pname = product?.name
            cell.lblQty.text = "\(cart.qty)"
            cell.lblTotal.text = "$\(cart.productSize.price! * Float(cart.qty))"
            cell.lblName.text = pname



        return cell
```

On the page, the output looks like this:

[image]

Right now if you order a hamburger, then put the cheeseburger into your cart, it will come up as ordering two cheeseburgers. What could I do to display the right information for all the items in the cart?

Here is the Tableview that populates everything:

```html
//Populate products in cart.
extension CartController: UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return    Cart.currentCart.items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shoppingCartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell
        
            let cart = Cart.currentCart.items[indexPath.row]
            let pname = self.product
            cell.lblQty.text = "\(cart.qty)"
            cell.lblTotal.text = "$\(cart.productSize.price! * Float(cart.qty))"
            cell.lblName.text = pname?.name

        
        
        
        return cell

        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: What does `print(Cart.currentCart.items)` log to the console?

Comment: It print out Johnny'sRestuarant.CartItem with all the appropriate data in it but, when put into a table object this happens @Carpsen90

Comment: Shouldn't the animation block be closed after `image.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: There was a UIAlert that I did not copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repetition of the product name means only one thing: `product` is not an array of products, it's one product, so `product?.name` will keep showing up. And apparently you're setting the `product` variable in the `Cart`class from the previous VC, you should make `product` an array instead, and append to it from the previous view controller.

The whole structure is confusing, maybe you're confusing `cart` with `product` in  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: How would I pass the entire array based on my previous vc?

Comment: you haven't shown the part where you're setting the `product`